# Why does Windows 10 display a different UTC time to .Net and SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows-10, utc

If I set up a clock in Windows 10 that displays UTC time:

[image]

It displays a date and time that is an hour different to the .Net DateTime.UtcNow() function and the SQL Server GETUTCDATE()

- SQL Server select GETUTCDATE() returns 2015-09-22 20:52:01.913
- .Net DateTime.UtcNow() is the same

Why is this? Which one is right? How do I get them the same?

Comment: Your bottom time is not UTC, it's UTC-11, that's a minus eleven hours.

Comment: I've tried to close this because the question is wrong. But I can only flag it for a moderator to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BryceWagner points out, despite the fact that you *named* the bottom clock "UTC", it's actually set to UTC-11 hours.

Change the dropdown to "(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time" (or the Windows 10 equivalent).